# Run slam without robot

Tags: ros, slam, ros-kinetic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I want to run slam as robot but I don't have any robot now. I just only have lidar sensor.
So I want to make a virtual map and run slam in a virtual map by moving virtual robot like this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lajIPkA86oQ

And I want to visualize point cloud data in rviz. My point cloud data is like this.
Can I visualize these point cloud data in rviz? or Can I create bag file by these point cloud data?

```
17.187 0.017 0.790 0.00
17.180 0.071 0.790 0.00
17.176 0.125 0.790 0.00
17.180 0.179 0.790 0.00
17.091 0.232 0.787 0.11
16.021 0.291 0.751 0.21
16.026 0.341 0.751 0.68
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298537/run-slam-without-robot./) by [js.kim.aspl@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36642/js.kim.aspl@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on 2018-10-02**:
Can you clarify the format of the file? What does each column represent?

If your file has:

1. the ranges or x/y coordinates of the scan from your lidar in the sensor's frame
2. a time stamp for each reading (I suppose that's not "technically" a requirement)
3. some odometry estimate
   ...

**Comment by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on 2018-10-02**:
the you can just write  anode that reads the file and publishes things to the correct topics (e.g. /scan, /odom, /tf, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

you can visualize Point cloud data in rviz. For this you just need to add right display. Please check this [manual](https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide). For storing bag file please check this [tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data).

For crating a map see these [tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials).

P.S. Next time when you want to ask a question try to search for it first. All this links were found in first 5 search results....

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [js.kim.aspl@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36642/js.kim.aspl@gmail.com/) on 2018-07-25**:
I already searched all things that you comment, but I am noobs so I think I've got it all figured out. Turorial that you comment explain how to create bag file by turtlesim node, my question is how to create bag just using point cloud data that is already collected before, not using turtlesim node.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-25**:
you should just choose your topic you want to record like:

```
rosbag record -O subset /cmd_vel
```

Where you intead of cmd_vel write name of your topic.